# Integrating vulnerability scan in AWS Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, antivirus, sam

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QcRg.png)We have 2 piplines one for building and deploying sam application and other for react application. How to integrate a new stage in that pipeline which can scan the build package for vulnerabilities and provide a report. Using any anti virus is fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqjgh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqjgh.png)

Comment: I feel like you would want to scan for vulnerabilities, it would not make much sense to scan for viruses as this stage.

Comment: yes  
Ervin Szilagyi

Comment: Usually you scan for vulnerabilities using a third party tool specific to the language you are coding in. For Javascript you can have something like Snyk vulnerability scanner, for Java there is SonerCube which can be configured to scan for vulnerabilities. There is a different setup for different use cases.

Comment: we are using backend nodejs lambdas and frontend react js

Comment: hi Ervin Szilagyi i used  this link and i integrated my aws codepipeline    https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/4402158184081   so i am facing this error

Comment: please any body knows my issue ?????

Comment: I suggest writing a new question with correct tags. This is not entirely aws related. I can not help you with this.

Comment: @boyapati edit your question and outline what you have tried and what's the error you are observing.

Comment: i am done aws sam codepipeline , ci cd process In there Process its involved api gateway , nodejs lambdas and api gateway methods so now I want to scan the codepipeline (like that after build ) , so what is the process  is there any way to do??? i arttach image also please check